# Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'GameObject'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
        foreach (GameObject target in targets)
        {
            objCount++;
            Animator targetAnimator = targets.GetComponent<Animator>();
            if (targetAnimator.GetInteger("Hit") == 1)
            {
                hitTargets++;
            }
        }
```

Error: CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'GameObject' because 'GameObject' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: What's the type of `targets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `foreach` is a sugar syntax to implement an iterator pattern let's use easy iterator a list or collection that needs to implement
`IEnumerable` interface if you want to use it in `foreach`

From your error, you can't use `targets` in foreach if that didn't implement `IEnumerable` interface (`GameObject`)

Maybe you can use

```
objCount++;
Animator targetAnimator = targets.GetComponent<Animator>();
if (targetAnimator.GetInteger("Hit") == 1)
{
    hitTargets++;
}
```